# How to connect to RESTful service with Spring from Android with HTTPS

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring RESTful server and it is all functional!

I have an Android client that I made using this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/ 
It is all functional as well, every link works.

But I need this to be HTTPS. I have already configured my server to be HTTPS and it is already working (tested it with the browser, everything working aswell).

Is there any way to consume this service with HTTPS? Given that Spring gave us an interface in the tutorial above, e.g.

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
```

Is there any interface to HTTPS?